# Visual Studio Installer 2022 doesn't produce registry keys

Tags: installation, windows-10, windows-installer, visual-studio-2022, setup-project

I'm trying my best to produce a foolproof installation methode for my programm.

I'm having the problem, that, eventhough it should be properly configured by me, my produced setup files won't produce any registry keys.

My Files are configured like this:
[image]

And my registry editing is looking like this:
[image]

I tried running the setup as an admin, but the keys just aren't created..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Go to the properties of your setup project and set the TargetPlatform to x86.

[image]

To set up the reg keys the right way you may try it like this:
[image]